# Windows Event Viewer - change log location?

Tags: windows-7, event-log, event-viewer, deep-freeze

I run a Windows 7 PC with DeepFreeze installed on it. So whenever my PC crashes (lately often), the Event Viewer logs are erased before reboot. Is there any way to set the log path manually so I can view them from a non-frozen drive?

Comment: run the pc without deepfreeze and look what happens. a tool that prevents changes to windows could cause crashes

Answer (score 1):

- Open "Event Viewer"
- Expand "Windows Logs"
- Right-click the log of your choice ("System", for example)
- Click "Properties"
- On the "General" Tab, change the path in the "Log Path" field.
- Click "OK"

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Enterprise edition, you can use the Deep Freeze Configuration Administrator to create a configuration that always retains Windows Event logs:

[image]